# symfony2 : sonata userbundle + fos userbundle + mongodb => error "sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager" does not exist

Tags: mongodb, symfony, service, sonata-user-bundle, usermanager

I'm trying to use Sonata/UserBundle with mongodb but I'm facing an issue.
I've got an ugly error:

> The service definition "sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager" does not
>   exist.

Here is the concerned configuration part :

```
# in app/config/config.yml
[...]
fos_user:
    db_driver: mongodb
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Project\MyApplicationBundle\Document\User

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager
[...]
```

If I comment the service part, it works but I have an empty document created in the DB when I add a new user.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that stable release of bundle version **2.2.4** has no **mongodb.xml** in Resources/config directory.

I changed development version (**~2.2@dev**) ant this works fine now.

now it looks like this: **"sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.2@dev"**